# Apache Server at boatandyachtbuyer.co.uk Port 80

Tags: magento-1.9, security, apache

Im having this weird problem in magento, when i try to log in the admin i was seeing this

> The requested URL /js/js.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache Server at example.co.uk Port 80

Answer (score 1):

This is malware, remove it from your site! Take your site offline. Change FTP/user passwords and perform a malware scan of your files.

Answer (score 0):

check your first lines in index.php in the root. In my case there was something placed by eclipse. Something like $x15='http://boatandyachtbuyer.co.uk'

I have deleted all these strange variables. Works like a charm.

Hope it helps.

Comment: May it be a result of some security issue on webserver or developer's computer?

Comment: Ronnie , did you find that line just in the index.php? because like you say, im having problems with every ajax call , products categories, saving products, all with the same error from that page